# Error installing requirements - google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I want to try pretrained model from https://github.com/dvlab-research/Stratified-Transformer

I run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

then

```
pip install torch_sparse==0.6.12
pip install torch_points3d==1.3.0
pip install tensorboard timm termcolor tensorboardX
```

but I get

```
..

!git clone https://github.com/dvlab-research/Stratified-Transformer
Cloning into 'Stratified-Transformer'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 225, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (27/27), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 225 (delta 23), reused 21 (delta 21), pack-reused 198
Receiving objects: 100% (225/225), 205.24 KiB | 293.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (94/94), done.
[3]
0 s
%cd /content/Stratified-Transformer
/content/Stratified-Transformer
[4]
2 min
!pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting h5py==3.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading h5py-3.2.1.tar.gz (368 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 368.2/368.2 kB 6.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Installing backend dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

```
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.52.0 Requires-Python >=3.6,<3.9; 0.52.0rc3 Requires-Python >=3.6,<3.9; 0.53.0 Requires-Python >=3.6,<3.10; 0.53.0rc1.post1 Requires-Python >=3.6,<3.10; 0.53.0rc2 Requires-Python >=3.6,<3.10; 0.53.0rc3 Requires-Python >=3.6,<3.10; 0.53.1 Requires-Python >=3.6,<3.10; 0.54.0 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10; 0.54.0rc2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10; 0.54.0rc3 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10; 0.54.1 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement open3d==0.10.0.0 (from torch-points3d) (from versions: 0.16.0, 0.17.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for open3d==0.10.0.0
```